# A movie clip above a simple button makes it unresponsive

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, flash

I have designed a menu in Flash CC which consists of several cloned buttons and an MC containing the text that is supposed to stay above the buttons. Each time a user switches the menu's page, AS commands the clip to switch to appropriate frames, therefore changing the text above buttons. And here's the catch: whenever you roll the cursor over the text itself, the button is not recognized as rolled over. It makes it feel really ugly and looks unprofessional. I tried setting the text MC's alpha to 99 with no effect. I know I can as well make a lot of the same buttons, each with different text, but something tells me there is a more efficient way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to disable mouse events on the text movie clip:

```
myMovieClip.mouseEnabled = false;
myMovieClip.mouseChildren = false;
```